# Display products in one subcategory - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new in woocommerce. I have a problem.

On my site, i have categories such us "Podnosniki", "Montażownice", "Wyważarki"

Tree look like this:

Podnosniki - this is category

- Podnosniki dwu-kolumnowe - this is subcategory in category "podnosniki"
- Podnosniki nozycowe
- Podnosniki podlogowe

When i enter to podnosniki, i have something like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3CvH.png)

I don't want display products from subcategories in category "podnosniki" (red field on screen)

How can i delete this section from all categories?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some code could be nice to help you :)

Comment: pastebin.com/0LXUX3Jy

Answer (score 0):

can you please explain more about your question? 
initially on woocommerce when you define a subcategory under a specific category the sub category contents are shown when you select main category and your problem is that you don't want to show subcategory contents when main category is selected?

Comment: I want display products only in last subcategories, nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin settings ...

WooCommerce -> Setiings -> Display

There you see a field (dropdown) name - 'Default category display'.

select 'show sub categories'.

Comment: only i can change display settings in that section (products or categories), i want delete this section. Can you show me, where can i find it?

Comment: what it is showing if you select 'show sub categories' ?

Comment: It duplicates. I want delete second section and want display products only in last subcategories, nowhere else.

Comment: Now with this situation if you select sub category ... are products getting displayed ?

Duplicate may be a different issue... but product display have gone from parent... which was your requirement.... 

And for duplicate display have you modified your theme code ?

Comment: This site was not create by me. I have some code in functions.php

Comment: In your theme, look for woocommerce template, there will be a file named 'archive-product.php'... which is responsible for generating this page.... You can tweak there..... But it is not recommended till it is possible by admin settings....

Comment: "I have some code in functions.php " -- That code you have to find out what it is doing.... If we know those codes... we can fix this easily.

Comment: good.... U can up vote/accept my answer if it correct/helped u @KrzysztofDomańczyk